# Is there an app for the dictionary DWDS?

Tags: dictionary

I really like the DWDS dictionary at https://www.dwds.de/

Is there an app so I can consult the dictionary offline?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly not. You can add the webpage to your home screen, but it won't work offline.

https://www.dwds.de/d/app

Comment: DWDS is part of the [BBAW](https://www.bbaw.de/), which is an academic rather than a commercial enterprise. I personally greatly appreciate the lack of spam on the site, but I suppose that implies there isn't too much in the way of funds for things like phone apps. Duden, on the other hand, does offer apps.